Update a doubly stochastic matrix
Let us say I have a doubly stochastic matrix, with the following constraints:

The rows and columns must sum upto 1
The diagonal is always 0

To give a realistic example
This matrix element P(i,j) describes the probability distribution of a directed connection existing between i to j, and there exists only one outgoing connection and one incoming connection for each node, which is why the rows and columns sum upto 1.
Now, let us say I have some new information, such that P(i,j) = p. How can I now update the matrix such that the properties are preserved, and I have a posterior distribution, that has incorporated this new information.
For example, let us say I know that P(3,5) = 1, i.e. there is a connection between 3 and 5 for sure. This means that the matrix must be updated such that P(i!=3,5) = 0 and also make some other adjustments to satisfy the matrix.
Thus, how can I go about incorporating this new information. I'd like to think this literature is present in some sources like Updating a MDP / factor graphs / MILP etc, but I'm a bit lost, and would need help.
I'm also open to a totally new form of representation as well, and not wedded to the stochastic matrix, but just naturally thought that was the best representation
Bonus: I would also like to solve the other information gain of: let us say, I want to increase the probability of P(i,j) by 0.1 since I am slightly more sure of it, can I incorporate the information in the same framework?

Possible idea too long for a comment. Here's an algorithm that might converge to what you want.
Suppose your new information is that $P(1,2) = t \le 1$. Then  rescale the first row, changing the other entries proportionally to make the row sum to $1$. (If $t=1$ then all the other entries in the first row will be $0$. If $t$ is less than what used to be there the other entries will increase.)
Rescaling the first row looks like this when you want to set $P(1,2) = t$:
let S = 1-P(1,2)     # sum of other old entries in row
    P(1,2) = t
    T = 1-t          # sum of other new entries in row   
for j != 2
    P(1,j) = (T/S)P(1,j)

Now the first row sums to $1$ with the new value of $P(1,2)$.
(If $S=0$ above then you knew the unique edge from 1 went to 2 and the other entries in the first row were $0$. If the new information is that $P(1,2) = t<1$ then make all the other entries in the first row equal to the value that makes the row sum $1$.)
Now the columns no longer sum to $1$, so rescale each so that the sum is correct (be sure to preserve $P(1,2) = t$.
Alternately rescale rows and columns until the resulting matrix is near enough to doubly stochastic.
(I have no proof that this will converge, but in a similar situation I used a similar algorithm when $t=0$ and could guarantee convergence if the original directed graph was connected enough.)

Can you elaborate a bit on "rescale each row/column, while preserving P(1,2) = t". How exactly do you do it.
Do I rescale, or subtract values from other entries

See  my edit ...
